# Bazel: How to make new_local_repository target depend on target generated by http_archive?

Tags: bazel, bazel-cpp

I have several third party libraries that depend on `openssl`, so I fetch and build openssl via repository mechanic (`http_archive()`). And I have GRPC that fetch `boringssl` that has same symbols that an openssl (after linking i get an error due collision).

I want to redefine `boringsll` using `new_local_repository()` method. But I don't known how to pass generated path to `path` argument and how make `new_local_repository()` call depend on `openssl` target.

The code that a want to get, looks like this:

```
new_local_repository(
  name = "boringssl",
  ??? path = "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/openssl/openssl/", <-- generated path with openssl
  build_file_content = """
cc_library(
  name = "ssl",
  deps = ["@openssl"],
  srcs = ["lib/libssl.a"],
  hdrs = glob(["include/openssl/*.h"]),
  strip_include_prefix = "/include/openssl",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
cc_library(
  name = "crypto",
  deps = ["@openssl"],
  srcs = ["lib/libcrypto.a"],
  hdrs = glob(["include/openssl/*.h"]),
  strip_include_prefix = "/include/openssl",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a replacement `@boringssl` with [alias](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#alias)es for each rule. Something like this as `third_party/boringssl/BUILD.bazel`:

```py
alias(
    name = "crypto",
    actual = "@openssl//:libcrypto",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Then you can ad it to your `WORKSPACE` with a relative path:

```py
local_repository(
    name = "boringssl",
    path = "third_party/boringssl",
)
```

This also lets you freely map target names if they differ. Alternatively, you could write `cc_library` wrappers (without `srcs`, just `deps`) to do things like combine multiple `@openssl` targets into a single one for the `@boringssl` equivalent.

With your approach, even if you use some hacks to reuse the repository directory or copy the source files, you will still have linking problems. Bazel will build all the `@openssl` source files twice and then try linking both copies in. The linker might just pick one and make everything work, or it might refuse to link, or you might get subtle problems at runtime with duplicated global state.